# Replication of Read only DC over firewall help?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, firewall

I have two domain controllers in two  separate VLANs. One of the DC(domain controllers) is win 2003 and other win 2008 r2.Win 2008 r2 is Read only Domain controller and in the same domain as win 2003.Now  I  want to configure the firewall so that replication over firewall between the VLAN is safe please help ??? I means which port should i open and  direstion of the connections?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, [you'll need another Win 2008r2 DC for the RODC to replicate from](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772065%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). A Read Only DC can't replicate domain data from a Win 2003 DC.

Secondly, there is an [extensive list of ports you need to open to allow domain replication over a firewall](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/179442). It's a large list.

**TCP Ports**

- 53
- 135
- 389
- 445
- 636
- 49152 - 65535 (RPC, though this can be restricted)
- 3268-3269

**UDP Ports**

- 53
- 88
- 123
- 138
- 389
- 445